# Eclipse "This selection cannot be launched and there are no recent launches" processing error

Tags: java, eclipse, processing

I've been trying to do processing in eclipse by downloading processing and running it with eclipse. Every time I try to run anything it says "This selection cannot be launched and there are no recent launches" **I've looked around for the same problem but none of them are for processing and mostly just for default java or android** I've tried to make a run configuration but to no avail.
code

```
import processing.core.PApplet;
import processing.core.PImage;


public class processing extends PApplet
{
PImage background;
PImage paddleImage;

public void setup()
{
    size(800, 600);
    background = loadImage("background.png");
    paddleImage = loadImage("paddle.png");
}
public void draw()
{
    background(background);
}
public class Paddle
{
    PImage sprite;
    float xPos;
    float yPos;

    public Paddle(PImage paddleSprite, float xStart, float yStart)
    {
        sprite = paddleSprite;
        xPos = xStart;
        yPos = yStart;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: For those confused about `processing` tag: ["Processing != Java"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321127/processing-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running in eclipse, you need a `main()` method.

```
public static void main(String... args){
    String[] pArgs = {"MySketch"};
    MySketch mySketch = new MySketch();
    PApplet.runSketch(pArgs, mySketch);
}
```

This code assumes you have a class named `MySketch` that extends `PApplet`.